# to Design Quality User Experience for Android Mobile app, should we care for pixel ? is that nessasory?

Tags: android

I am troubling and confused to design android Mobile app. I want to design perfect app so can any one help me to trace out my problem and solve it??

here is my problem

to Design User Experience for Android Mobile app, should we care for pixel ? is that necessary ?

If necessary than how to design with pixel perfection??

I try to get help from google but no one is perfect for the quality.

What should be size of photoshop document for any individual page.??
what should be navbar size ? 
what should be icon size for nav bar ?

I am confuesed due to varity of sizes and DPI for android devices.. so please help me a little to solve this...

Here is a [link](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#google-play-asset-dimensions) from android about sizes but i do now know how to implement it.?

Comment: I think Android Stack Exchange might be a good place for your question. Also, even if you go pixel-perfect with elements in your UI, Android's different form factors require that you have a good scaling mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always consult developer.android.com for questions regarding system norms and design guidelines.

For pixel perfect designs you may want to look into 9-patch images using 9-patch for your buttons and other layouts such as cards will allow your designs to scale without blur or distortion.

As for any icons you will need to simply calculate their dimensions for hdpi, xhdpi, etc. And put them in their respective folders.

By the way this is probably not the right forum for this question. But I'll answer it anyways because I believe that it's the little design details that really create an amazing experience in the end.